# Navbar wont collapse in rails app using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys I have a rails app styled with bootstrap via railsassets, I have a navbar that will expand but wont collapse on toggle.  From what I've read on here the solution is to host the js from an online source, but I'm already doing that.  Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Cable Blade: Cut Your Cable Bill</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="/assets/application-3c8a5eb3858888951e26c6d071a21305.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="/assets/application-6c4abb164efadf56cf17347c4d676b7b.js"></script>


  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body style="background-color:#f3f3f3;text-align:center;color:000000;">

<!-- CONTENT -->
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- NAV -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand & Toggle grouped for mobile device -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Cable Blade</a>
      </div>
<!-- Collect nav links for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- container-fluid -->
  </nav>
<!-- END NAV -->

  </div>
<!-- END CONTENT -->

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: your code seems to be fine. I think you need to open your console in the browser to see what error is returned.

Comment: I don't see any errors about this event, the only issues I can see is the facebook like code returns Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id, and the google adsense code returns Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT